# SPI1 on Pandaboard ES Rev. B2 with Kernel 3.17

Tags: linux-kernel, spi, device-tree, pandaboard

This is the first time I ask a question on stackoverflow.

I tried to access SPI1 on the J3 of my Pandaboard ES.  First, I modified the device tree source, omap4-panda-es-b3.dts, by adding

```
&mcspi1
{
    spidev@0
    {
        compatible = "spidev";
        pinctrl-name = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&spi1_pins>;
        spi-max-frequency=<4000000>;
        reg = <0>;
    };
};
```

and

```
spi1_pins: pinmux_spi1_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0xf2 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0)   /* spi1_sclk, gpio134 */
                0xf4 (PIN_INPUT_PULLUP  | MUX_MODE0)   /* spi1_somi, gpio135 */
                0xf6 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0)   /* spi1_simo, gpio136 */
                0xf8 (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0)   /* spi1_somi, gpio137 */
        >;
};
```

Then, rebuilt the kernel, installed the new kernel and rebooted.  The device spidev1.0 showed in the /dev directory as well as /sys/class/spidev.

But when I did "echo 1 > /dev/spi1.0" or ran spi_test from [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c), nothing came out from the SPI1 pins on the scope.  I have double checked the offsets and am sure that they should be correct.

What do I need to do so the SPI1 on the Pandaboard ES works? The output of "uname -a" is

```
Linux arm 3.17.4-USER1-armv7-x3 #4 SMP Tue Feb 17 19:35:52 CST 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks

MST

Comment: Maybe this can be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707808/uart4-with-pandaboard-and-arch-linux/32725769#32725769