# UART4 with Pandaboard and Arch Linux

Tags: linux, device-tree, pandaboard, archlinux-arm

I'm trying to use `UART4` in my Pandaboard with Arch Linux. I'm using the latest kernel (4.2.0-2-ARCH) so I can't configure MUX in the old way using `omap_mux`, I have to do it using Device Tree Overlay. This is new to me so it's hard, I've never done this before. I have been reading some post about how to use them in Beaglebone boards in sites like [this](http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/beaglebone-black/step04-gpio/) and [this](http://interactingobjects.com/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-on-a-beaglebone-black-running-ubuntu/). So I downloaded the OMAP4 Technical Reference Manual (download [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swpu235ab/swpu235ab.pdf)). **Table 18-504** shows the `UART4` control register. Based on that and the urls above I created and compiled the following Device Tree Overlay filling the register with 0's, this should set the MUX for `UART4` functionality:

```
// Util: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4-panda-es.dts
//       http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/beaglebone-black/step04-gpio/


/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;


/ {
        model = "TI OMAP4 PandaBoard-ES";
        compatible = "ti,omap4-panda-es", "ti,omap4460";


        part-number = "ANDRES-IO";


        fragment@0 {
                target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
                __overlay__ {
                        uart4_pins: pinmux_uart4_pins {
                                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                                        0x15C 0x00  // kernel pin 142 (uart4 tx y rx - address 0x4A10 015C)
                                                      >;
                        };
                };
        };


        fragment@1 {
                target = <&ocp>;
                __overlay__ {
                        uart4_pins_helper {
                                compatible = "panda-pinmux-helper";
                                pinctrl-names = "default";
                                pinctrl-0 = <&uart4_pins>;
                                status = "okay";
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

I copied the compiled file to /lib/firmware/ but after that I don't know how to use or enable it. Beaglebone boards have bone_capemgr but I can't see such a thing in Pandaboard.

Other OS like Ubuntu has `UART4` already configured, I tried looking for the Device Tree Overlay they use but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!!!! Maybe is something trivial but it was really hard for me and I learned a lot. There is no much info about how to do it in Pandaboard, just for Beagleboards. So first, the `Device Tree Overlay` file it's loaded only at boot, we can't load it dynamically as with Beagleboard because we don't have a `bone_capemgr`. The compiled `.dtb` file is located in `/boot/dtbs` (at least in Arch Linux), there are a lot of `.dtb` files there but only one is loaded at boot depending on the board and you can see which one is loaded when booting, for example, in my case it is:

```
U-Boot 2015.04 (Jun 07 2015 - 19:26:06) Arch Linux ARM
CPU  : OMAP4460 ES1.1
Board: OMAP4 Panda
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  1 GiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0
** Unable to use mmc 0:1 for loading the env **
Using default environment
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
starting USB...
USB0:   USB EHCI 1.00
scanning bus 0 for devices... 3 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
       scanning usb for ethernet devices... 1 Ethernet Device(s) found
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
mmc found on device 0
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
74 bytes read in 13 ms (4.9 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from /boot/uEnv.txt
Checking if uenvcmd is set ...
4984312 bytes read in 244 ms (19.5 MiB/s)
loading /boot/dtbs/omap4-panda-es.dtb ...
100695 bytes read in 380 ms (257.8 KiB/s)
** File not found /boot/initramfs-linux.img **
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x4c0df8 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8ffe4000, end 8ffff956 ... OK
Starting kernel ...
```

I have a Pandaboard ES so the loaded file is `/boot/dtbs/omap4-panda-es.dtb`. I decompiled the file so I can add the UART4 MUX settings using `dtc -I dtb -O dts omap4-panda-es.dtb > omap4-panda-es.dts` (taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hbrobotics/u-Y5PGCpPw8)). So now we have a `omap4-panda-es.dts` which is the complete Device Tree Overlays that sets everything up, I just need to add the UART4 MUX settings. We have to use the `pinctrl-single,pins` property. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.adafruit.com%2Fintroduction-to-the-beaglebone-black-device-tree%2Fdevice-tree-overlays&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGlD1BZPs-ofgaMFPF1OmBMD4IrRA) is a really good explanation about `pinctrl-single,pins`:

> The pin configuration nodes for pinctrl-single are specified as
>   pinctrl register offset and value pairs using pinctrl-single,pins.
>   Only the bits specified in pinctrl-single,function-mask are updated.
>   For example, setting a pin for a device could be done with:
>   pinctrl-single,pins = <0xdc 0x118>; Where 0xdc is the offset from the
>   pinctrl register base address for the device pinctrl register, and
>   0x118 contains the desired value of the pinctrl register.

This was something I misunderstood at the beginning, I though the `pinctrl` address was absolute but it's relative to the base address in the tree. In my case for example there are a lot of `pinmux_tfp410_pins`, `pinmux_dss_hdmi_pins`, `pinmux_i2c1_pins`, etc. All these `pinmux_*`  are under a parent called `pinmux@40`, that means that the address specified in `pinctrl` is relative to `0x40`, but this `pinmux@40` is under another node called `scm@100000` which is inside another node called `l4@4a000000`, so the addresses inside `pinmux@40` are relative to the base address of the node that is the sum of all these addresses, that is `0x4a000000 + 0x100000 + 0x40 = 0x4a100040`, so `0xa100040` is the base address, all the address specified in `pinctrl` are relative to `0xa100040`. So, according to **Table 18-504** in the `OMAP4 Technical Reference Manual` (download available [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fug%2Fswpu235ab%2Fswpu235ab.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHUJrYLdyNunYRtQaod6MeTfxg7Qw)) the address for the UART4 control register that control the MUX and some other things is `0x4A10015C`. The base address of pinctrl is `0x4a100040` so the address we must specify in `pinctrl` is `0x11c` because `0x4a100040 + 0x11c = 0x4A10015C`. All the Device Tree Overlays I found of other linux distros that support Pandaboard use the same base address `0x4a100040` ([here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2F198.47.29.151%2Fandroid-sdk%2Fkernel-video%2Fblobs%2Ff76170d52786213b070893ced5f0933d7a5c6674%2Farch%2Farm%2Fboot%2Fdts%2Fomap4-sdp.dts&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGvvPsDB6G84OVCVMru7PC3lX5m8g) for example). So I added under the node `pinmux@40` this:

```
// Set the UART4 MUX, it doesn't come by default so I had to add it
//  "linux,phandle" has the same value aas "phandle", it's just a reference number, just make sure
//  it is not being used in another part of the tree (it will refuse to compile if you do it wrong)
// The phandle is used for reference in "serial@4806e000" at "pinctrl-0"
pinmux_uart4_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x11c 0x100       // uart4_rx.uart4_rx INPUT | MODE0
        0x11e 0           // uart4_tx.uart4_tx OUTPUT | MODE0
    >;
    linux,phandle = <0xfff>;
    phandle = <0xfff>;
};
```

I took this settings from [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2F198.47.29.151%2Fandroid-sdk%2Fkernel-video%2Fblobs%2Ff76170d52786213b070893ced5f0933d7a5c6674%2Farch%2Farm%2Fboot%2Fdts%2Fomap4-sdp.dts&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGvvPsDB6G84OVCVMru7PC3lX5m8g) but just changing the `0x100` and `0` will change the settings in the register. In my case I also had to add:

```
linux,phandle = <0xfff>;
phandle = <0xfff>;
```

I don't see this in Ubuntu for example (https://github.com/Canonical-kernel/Ubuntu-kernel/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4.dtsi) but I don't know why or what is the purpose of this `phandle`, all I know if that they are used as a reference, a reference I need to put somewhere else in the Device Tree, just make sure it is unique, it can be any 32-bit value but must be unique inside the tree. In my case there was another node referring UART4:

```
serial@4806e000 {
     compatible = "ti,omap4-uart";
     reg = <0x4806e000 0x100>;
     interrupts = <0x0 0x46 0x4>;
     ti,hwmods = "uart4";
     clock-frequency = <0x2dc6c00>;
     interrupts-extended = <0x1 0x0 0x46 0x4 0x82 0x11c>;
     linux,phandle = <0x121>;
      phandle = <0x121>;
 };
```

So there I had to use `phandle` otherwise MUX settings won't be applied:

```
 serial@4806e000 {
     compatible = "ti,omap4-uart";
     reg = <0x4806e000 0x100>;
     interrupts = <0x0 0x46 0x4>;
     ti,hwmods = "uart4";
     pinctrl-names = "default";
     pinctrl-0 = <0xfff>;
     clock-frequency = <0x2dc6c00>;
     interrupts-extended = <0x1 0x0 0x46 0x4 0x82 0x11c>;
     linux,phandle = <0x121>;
     phandle = <0x121>;
 };
```

Finally, at the end of the file there a lot of definitions, one for each node, for example

```
i2c1_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_i2c1_pins";
i2c2_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_i2c2_pins";
i2c3_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_i2c3_pins";
i2c4_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_i2c4_pins";
wl12xx_gpio = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_wl12xx_gpio";
wl12xx_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_wl12xx_pins";
twl6030_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_twl6030_pins";
```

They just describe where each node is located, here we can clearly see what the base address is. So here I just added this:

```
uart4_pins = "/ocp/l4@4a000000/scm@100000/pinmux@40/pinmux_uart4_pins";
```

Now we have a complete `.dts` file which should get the UART4 working. We must compile it using `dtc -O dtb -o omap4-panda-es.dtb -b O -@ omap4-panda-es.dts`, this will generate a `.dtb` file that will replace the one in `/boot/dtbs`, so replace it and reboot! After rebooting run `cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/4a100040.pinmux/pinmux-functions`, it should show something like this:

```
function: pinmux_dss_dpi_pins, groups = [ pinmux_dss_dpi_pins ]
function: pinmux_tfp410_pins, groups = [ pinmux_tfp410_pins ]
function: pinmux_dss_hdmi_pins, groups = [ pinmux_dss_hdmi_pins ]
function: pinmux_tpd12s015_pins, groups = [ pinmux_tpd12s015_pins ]
function: pinmux_hsusbb1_pins, groups = [ pinmux_hsusbb1_pins ]
function: pinmux_uart4_pins, groups = [ pinmux_uart4_pins ]
function: pinmux_wl12xx_pins, groups = [ pinmux_wl12xx_pins ]
function: gpio_led_pmx, groups = [ gpio_led_pmx ]
function: pinmux_wl12xx_gpio, groups = [ pinmux_wl12xx_gpio ]
function: pinmux_i2c1_pins, groups = [ pinmux_i2c1_pins ]
function: pinmux_twl6030_pins, groups = [ pinmux_twl6030_pins ]
function: pinmux_twl6040_pins, groups = [ pinmux_twl6040_pins ]
function: pinmux_i2c2_pins, groups = [ pinmux_i2c2_pins ]
function: pinmux_i2c3_pins, groups = [ pinmux_i2c3_pins ]
function: pinmux_i2c4_pins, groups = [ pinmux_i2c4_pins ]
function: pinmux_wl12xx_pins, groups = [ pinmux_wl12xx_pins ]
function: pinmux_mcpdm_pins, groups = [ pinmux_mcpdm_pins ]
function: pinmux_mcbsp1_pins, groups = [ pinmux_mcbsp1_pins ]
```

If we see `uart4` everything is fine and it should be working! Otherwise there is something wrong in the `.dts` file. We can test if the uart is working by running for example `echo -e "AT" > /dev/ttyO3`, remember that `/dev/ttyO3` is `UART4`. I hope this will be useful for someone!

Just for reference here is the complete `.dts` and compiled `.dtb` file with working UART4: https://gist.github.com/dragondgold/1aaabf93279006b703f3